# Python check if directory exists using for loop and list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, exists

I want to see if some directories exists. The script is sayings it doesnt exist but i know it does.

I think it has something to do with the string being stored in the list in this format (double backslash):
"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"

when i store the path into a object it runs fine.
eg
path = "\\servername\path1\evv\path2"

```
import os 

x =["env1","env2","env3","env4"]
j=[]
for env in x:
    q=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    w=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    e=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    r=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    t=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    y=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    u=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    i=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    o=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    p=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    a=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    s=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    d=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    f=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    g=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    h=r"\\servername\\path1\\"+env+"\\path2"
    j.extend((q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h))



for path in j:
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print "It Exists"
    else:
        print "It doesnt Exist"
print j
```

["\\servername\path1\"+env+"\path2"]

Comment: You're using raw strings **and** double backslashes.

Comment: I no - it doesn't make a difference. I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop was needed to output the list into the correct format

```
for string in j:
    print string
    if os.path.exists(string):
        print "It Exists"
    else:
        print "It doesnt Exist"
```